# Java Http Client to support 50K req/min

Tags: java, retrofit2, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a use case where I want to make at least 50K POST req/min to a downstream service.

Here, the main thing I want to achieve is

- Low Latencies
- Close to ZERO Socket Timeouts

I tried retrofit2 and Apache HTTP client, both are giving high latencies and many SocketTimeouts.

Comment: Are you talking about stress test or a production case? Also do you distribute your client calls? I believe whatever client you choose, 50K/min would load your host system pretty much which could back-impact your client.

Comment: @AlexeyR. 
This is the production use case. We do have multiple instances of service running. The client is capable of taking 1.5Lac req/min.